# how to automatically infer header with multiple rows while reading csv in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which looks like below.

```
                A1          A2  A3
                Top         Up  Side
                m3          kg  psi
6/12/2012 10:57 1568.5707   7   1460.55
6/12/2012 10:58 1561.3742   6   1460.55
6/12/2012 10:59 1533.0108   8   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:00 1551.1134   10  1460.55
6/12/2012 11:01 1576.0391   7   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:02 1559.4298   7   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:03 1564.0189   10  1460.55
6/12/2012 11:04 1547.7717   9   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:05 1554.6839   5   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:06 1590.4266   7   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:07 1567.4878   9   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:08 1554.7701   6   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:09 1547.7278   8   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:10 1575.9325   7   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:11 1563.1524   6   1460.55
6/12/2012 11:12 1579.9714   5   1460.55
```

where the first column is the index column with date and time. The first 3 rows contain alphanumeric characters such as units and descriptions of the data. From 4th row ,the data is numeric , and there are 16 rows of data.  I expected, that with default `header='infer'`, option for `read_csv`, pandas would automatically infer the first 3 rows as a header, and return the dataframe with 16 rows of data. However,it does not happen. Instead pandas infers only the first row as the header ,and returns dataframe with 18 rows of data ,including the descriptions and units. I know I can explicitly specify header rows with  `header=[0,1,2]` option to force pandas to use header rows supplied by the user. However , any idea how to infer multiple header rows automatically ? To be more specific , how to make pandas infer all the rows with alpha numeric characters as header rows and only use numeric rows as the data.